# What events, conditions and actions I should use for this case?

Tags: rules, commerce, actions

I use "commerce" and "commerce stock" modules, I created a list with products and a few extra fields in **Product types**:
- Image
- Deposit 1 Stock
- Deposit 2 Stock
- Deposit 3 Stock

I created a view (table - http://ucreateawebsite.com/DRUPAL/dalexgrup/pt)  with this fields: 
- Bulk Operations
- SKU
- Imagine
- Title
- Deposit 1 Stock
- Deposit 2 Stock
- Deposit 3 Stock

I have a problem in succeeding to create another stock field (the fourth - called **TOTAL STOCK**) and making it to automatically update when the other 3 fields are being changed. I want the fourth field to calculate and show me the sum of the other 3 fields.

---

- Example 1 *
  Deposit 1 Stock -> 15
  Deposit 2 Stock -> 15

  ### Deposit 3 Stock -> 15

### TOTAL STOCK -> 45

---

- Example 2 *
  Deposit 1 Stock -> 10
  Deposit 2 Stock -> 05

  ### Deposit 3 Stock -> 01

### TOTAL STOCK -> 16

This **TOTAL STOCK field** I should create in **Product type** like:
- Deposit 1 Stock
- Deposit 2 Stock
- Deposit 3 Stock ??????

Then I should create a rule? What events, conditions and actions I should use?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

***For Event I used:***

### 1. After updating an existing commerce product

***For Conditions I used:***

### 1. Entity has field - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_stock1

### 2. Entity has field - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_stock2

### 3. Entity has field - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_stock3

### 4. Entity has field - Parameter: Entity: [commerce-product], Field: field_totalstock

***For Actions I used:***

### 1. Calculate a value - Parameter: Input value 1: [commerce-product:field-stock1], Input value 2: [commerce-product:field-stock2]; Provides variables: Calculation result for Stock1  and Stock2 (stock1_plus_stock2_result)

### 2. Calculate a value - Parameter: Input value 1: [stock1-plus-stock2-result], Input value 2: [commerce-product:field-stock3]; Provides variables: Calculation result for stock1-plus-stock2-result and Stock3 (stock1_plus_stock2_result_plus_stock3)

### 3. Set a data value - Parameter: Data: [commerce-product:field-totalstock], Value: [stock1_plus_stock2_result_plus_stock3]

You can see what I wrote here -> http://ucreateawebsite.com/DRUPAL/dalexgrup/pt